# Java Interface Observable

Tags: java, interface, observable

I have the following:

1. A Java class: ClassA implements Observer
2. A Java Interface: Inter (extends Observable, not possible)
3. A Java class: ClassB implements Inter extends Observable
4. A Java class: ClassC implements Inter extends Observable

Now the code for ClassA is somewhat like this.

```
ClassA{
    Inter anyClass = new ClassB();
           //or it could be
    Inter anyClass = new ClassC();
    //Inter.addObserver(this); //not possible since Interface cannot extend Observable
}
```

Now if a particular event happens in ClassB or ClassC, I want ClassA to know about it. I thought of using the Observer/Observable but the problem is that the Interface cannot extend Observable.

If someone understands the question please help me find a way to update ClassA when something happens in ClassB or ClassC.

Comment: Pass in ClassA to the constructors of ClassB or ClassC. They notify A when something changes?

Comment: Is there a difference between 'Observer' and 'Observable'? Also, when you say 'Update ClassA' what do you mean? Update a particular instance of that class or the class itself? What is the update exactly?

Comment: Hi Nathaniel, 

I was looking at implementing the Observer/Observable design pattern. Java already has a built in support for it so I was trying to use it but it looks like I might not be able to do this.

Answer (score 5):

You don't specifically have to use the built-in Observer/Observable java implementation. You can create your own interfaces to use the observer pattern.

Create an interface Observer with the method 'update' or 'notify' (or something like that) which will be used for ClassA

then to use the 'Inter' interface to act as an Observable make sure it implements the following:

```
- registerObserver(Observer)
- unregisterObserver(Observer)
- notifyObservers() //(or updateObservers(), which calls the update/notify method for all registered observers)
```

Make sure classes that implement the 'Inter' interface also have an arraylist called observerCollection to keep track of the observers. Then everytime something changes in ClassB or ClassC and you want to tell ClassA (the observer) you can call notifyObservers() to let it know something has changed.

Take a look at this to see what happens with the observer design pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Observer.svg

Answer (score 2):

By the 3 and 4 conditions I assume that Observable is a class, because ClassB and ClassC are extending it. So, why don't you put the addObserver method in Observable class? Then you could assign ClassB or ClassC instances to an Observable anyClass variable, and register the observer via addObserverMethod:

```
ClassA implements Observer {
    Observable anyClassB = new ClassB();
       //or it could be
    Observable anyClassC = new ClassC();
    anyClassB.addObserver(this);
    anyClassC.addObserver(this);
}
```

Comment: +1: `Observable` is a class supplied in the JDK.  However, it does already have an `addObserver` method, and this is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Thanks. I will do this for now. However as @jagsler suggested creating my own implementation of the Observer/Observable pattern might be a better approach. I will look into that too.

Answer (score 2):

Simply define your own interface *IObservable* with the appropriates methods *addObserver* and *deleteObserver*:

```
public interface IObservable {
    void addObserver(Observer o);    
    void deleteObserver(Observer o);    
}
```

Your interface can extend this *IObservable* interface:

```
public interface inter extends IObservable {
...
}
```

In your class A and B, the *addObserver* and *deleteObserver* methods will be inherited from the Observable class and do not need to be defined.

```
public class A extends Observable implements inter {
...
}
```